# How to set userinteractionEnabled: to NO for an AVPlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, setuserinteractionenabled

I try to set userinteractionEnabled: to NO for an AVPlayerViewController

```
[playerViewController setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

but I have an error

```
"No visible @interface for 'AVPlayerViewController' declares the selector 'setUserInteractionEnabled:'"
```

No visible @interface 
Here is my complete code:

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
playerViewController.player = player;
  playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false;    
    [playerViewController.player play];
[playerViewController setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:playerViewController animated:YES];
[self performSelector:@selector(popToMain) withObject:nil afterDelay:durationInSeconds];
```

I just would like the people cannot click on the screen during the video.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

or this:

```
 playerViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Oh I am so stupid, I forgot the .view... my mistake... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this might help you:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```